# website name is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 #RewriteCond www.%{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(www\..+)$ [NC]
 #RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the .htaccess file 
and my config file is this

```
  $config['base_url'] = 'http://website.org/';
  $config['index_page'] = '';
```

This was working perfect on beta server but getting 500 error on live server.

Comment: what about only once using the line `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125796/internal-server-error-in-codeigniter-on-live-host/45125858#45125858), check `.htaccess`, `db` and `config` file

Comment: The absolute first thing you always do on a 500 Internal Server Error, is you go check the relevant log files. (-1 for still having to explain that to a “software engineer”.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i have ask this question after using all the options the error log the error mode it does not show anything.

Comment: request is not going into my main controller's  contructure.

Answer (score 0):

Check below mentioned code for `.htaccess` in `codeigniter`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|js|docs|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Let me know if you still have 500 Error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this below code :in your .htaccess files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

Before this you need to check is Mod.rewrite has enabled in your live server if not then you need to enable from

**Php.ini -> ;mod_rewrite to remove (;) from php.ini files**